# Merge objects with same value

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to add a value from one object to another if both have the same value.

This is how the objects looks like basically:

```
var comments = [
  {
    author: '4jdf7s',
    message: 'Comment text here',
    posted: '2014-12-29 14:30'
  },
  {
    author: '87sd3w',
    message: 'Comment text here',
    posted: '2014-12-30 12:00'
  }
];

var users = [
  {
    _id: '87sd3w',
    username: 'MyUsername'
  },
  {
    _id: '4jdf7s',
    username: 'OtherUsername'
  }
];
```

And as `author` and `_id` is the same, I want to add `users.username` to `comments.username` like this:

```
var comments = [
  {
    author: '4jdf7s',
    username: 'OtherUsername',
    message: 'Comment text here',
    posted: '2014-12-29 14:30'
  },
  {
    author: '87sd3w',
    username: 'MyUsername',
    message: 'Comment text here',
    posted: '2014-12-30 12:00'
  }
];
```

The `comments` object has been sorted, which is why it can't be scrambled aswell.

This is my current code but it doesn't work at all:

```
comments.forEach(function(i, index) {
  users.forEach(function(e) {
    if(e._id == i.author) {
      comments[index].username = e.username;
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The callback for `Array.forEach` has the *object* as the first parameter, not the index. So change to this:

```
comments.forEach(function(comment) {
    users.forEach(function(user) {
        if (user._id === comment.author) {
            comment.username = user.username;
        }
    });
});
```

Would like to also point out that nested loops like this are notoriously a bad idea with large sets of data; it has an `O(N*M)` complexity. In addition, once you find a match, the loop continues. I'd recommend you create a lookup of the users first so that each lookup is an `O(1)`, converting the overall code to `O(N)`:

```
var usersById = {};
users.forEach(function(user) { usersById[user._id] = user; });

comments.forEach(function(comment) {
    var user = usersById[comment.author];
    if (user) {
        comment.username = user.username;
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you for the response! I tried with your code, but it doesn't seem to work either, as this is what I'm getting back when logging comments: `[ { author: 54a34906af18e2a3db4dff30,
    message: 'Somerandomtextgoeshere2',
    posted: Wed Dec 31 2014 01:53:26 GMT+0100 (CET) },
  { author: 54a34906af18e2a3db4dff2f,
    message: 'Somerandomtextgoeshere',
    posted: Wed Dec 31 2014 01:53:26 GMT+0100 (CET) } ]` Maybe async issues?

Comment: I'd use a step debugger and see what's going on. Maybe `users` doesn't have what you think, or `_id` and `author` don't match, or something like that.

Comment: It finds matches, so it is working but it's like `comment.username = user.username;` doesn't write to the original `comments` object?

Comment: I added a `console.log(comment.username);` and it prints the correct username, but when I do `console.log(comments);` after the forEach loop it doesn't exist in there, it's the same as the unmodified one so the line `comment.username = user.username` does not write back to the original `comments` variable.

Comment: That doesn't make sense, The `comment` should be the exact same object as the one in the `Array`. Is there something more complicated going on that's not posted here, like some JSON parsing?

Comment: Seems like the object was locked from mongoose, got it fixed now, thanks! Happy new year!

Answer (score 1):

You can precache authors to avoid inner loop.

```
var cache = users.reduce(function(acc, user){
  acc[user._id] = user.name; 
  return acc;}, {}
);
comments.forEach(function(comment){
  comment.username = cache[comment.author];
});
```